# selected value in select should be at top when editing a form

Tags: php

I am editing my form but i am facing a problem in select tag. I want the already selected value at the top of the option and plus same value should not be shown twice. Below i am getting the selected value at the top but i don't know how to overcome the duplicate value. I am new to php and i don't know if this is a ridiculous question or not. Any help would be nice.

I am using two tables `Status` and other is `Cases`. First option is from `Status` and second one is from `Cases`.

```
<select name='cstatus' style="width: 100%;">
   <option><?=$row['CASE_STATUS']?></option>
   echo "<option value='".$row['CASE_NAME']."'>".$row['CASE_NAME'].'</option>';
<select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selected="selected"` on the option you want to be selected.

That way you don't have to duplicate the option to put it at the top.

Comment: but i am accessing the selected value from database. there should be a random value placed in the databse out of say 5 options. what can i do in this case?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your problem. What's in your database? Which option do you want to select by default?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if($row['CASE_STATUS'] == "")
{
   echo "<option>Under Investigation</option>";
   echo "<option>Under Trial</option>";
}

else if($row['CASE_STATUS'] == "Under Investigation")
{
   echo '<option>'.$row["CASE_STATUS"].'</option>';
   echo "<option>Under Trial</option>";
}

else
{
   echo '<option>'.$row["CASE_STATUS"].'</option>';
   echo "<option>Under Investigation</option>";
}
?>
```